# Trying to install React Keyed File Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, raspberry-pi

I have a website that I use to download common files that I need. I want to use this to display the files: https://github.com/uptick/react-keyed-file-browser

I have a raspberry pi that I run my website off of. I installed npm and ran the command from that github page (npm install react-keyed-file-browser) with success but I'm confused as to how to do the next step. Where does this go?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import FileBrowser from 'react-keyed-file-browser'

var mount = document.querySelectorAll('div.browser-mount');
ReactDOM.render(
  <FileBrowser
    files=[]
  />,
  mount[0]
);
```

Thanks a ton! I'm sorry I'm so clueless.

Comment: You will need an html document that has a `div` in it with the `class` 'browser-mount' assigned as an attribute. Then this code would go in to a script file or as script inline in the page using a `script` tag.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll give it a shot.